# select_by_value causing odd issue with the DOM

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

I'm new to Python and Selenium testing so please forgive me if this isn't written right. I've been asked to look at the test that does a few actions on a form. The form has 2 text fields, a drop down, and a button. The test is rather simple:

```
self.wd.wait_for_css('.js-status-code-input').send_keys('100')
self.wd.find_css('.js-description-input').send_keys('Approved')

status_select = Select(self.wd.find_css('.js-status-input'))
status_select.select_by_value('APPRV')

self.wd.wait_for_css('#js-add-mapping-btn').click()
```

When run, we get an error at the very end: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

So - I did some debugging and noticed something odd. When select_by_value is run, the entire form goes away. And in fact, if I look at the position of js-add-mapping-btn, it has a y value set above the top of the browser. Before select_by_value, it is normal.

To make things even more interesting, if I change APPRV to whatever is the default option, it doesn't make the form disappear and the test passes.

If I use select_by_index, it is the exact same behavior. Using 1 as a value causes the bug, using 0 makes it pass.

So it seems like select_by_value, when it changes stuff, is breaking the site. I've removed any client-side JS code validation on the form. I've also tested manually, in the same browser, entering the same values, and I can't reproduce what I see when the webdriver drives Firefox along.

**Edit on Sep 2**
I was gone for a few days on vacation and my coworker made some discoveries. What follows is credit Alan Greenblatt:

Aha! I've made some progress on this one. I stepped into status_select.select_by_value('APPRV'), which is defined as:

```
def select_by_value(self, value):
    """Select all options that have a value matching the argument. That is, when given "foo" this
       would select an option like:

       <option value="foo">Bar</option>

       :Args:
        - value - The value to match against
       """
    css = "option[value =%s]" % self._escapeString(value)
    opts = self._el.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)
    matched = False
    for opt in opts:
        self._setSelected(opt)
        if not self.is_multiple:
            return
        matched = True
    if not matched:
        raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
```

Then I stopped on the 'self._setSelected(opt)' line. All is still good in the UI at this point. If you print out 'opt', the UI goes kerflooey. So, I tried printing out each attribute of opt individually. It turns out that the problem occurs only when you try to resolve opt.location_once_scrolled_into_view.

In the firefox driver js source, it looks like this will actually scroll the element into view. I'm betting this is where the problem lies.

**and then later**

I stopped at the same line, but then went into Firefox's Web Developer debugger and executed the following line:

```
$.find('.js-status-input')[0].options[1].scrollIntoView()
```

and was able to reproduce the problem.

**and then later again...**

And interestingly,

```
$.find('.js-status-input')[0].options[1].scrollIntoView(false)
```

looks good, but

```
$.find('.js-status-input')[0].options[1].scrollIntoView(true) or $.find('.js-status-input')[0].options[1].scrollIntoView()
```

does not

Comment: Please try a wait statement in between your `select_by_value` and your `click()`.  3 seconds should be fine.  See if the screen refreshes and appears normal again or if it stays broken.

Comment: Did you mean time.sleep?

Comment: Yes.  Just to see if it is due to acting to quickly after selection.

Comment: I did - no change. I can post a screen shot if you want. As soon as select_by_value runs, most, not all, of the UI goes away. It's insane. :) Btw - I posted this last night and today I'm going out of town. I may be slow to respond for 5 days. That was dumb on my part, but pls note I *greatly* appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too specific

Comment: Is there a JS action occurring when the select is changed that could be refreshing the page?

Comment: Sorry - I no longer work on this project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too specific, answer is no longer required